# Polyethylene terephthalate reaction with tap water

Tags: plastics

I have searched the internet and I found that reusing PET no.1 is dangerous. Why it is dangerous and what is the equation of the reaction between it and water tap ? And why it is not danger to when it is used for the first time in water bottles but it is danger when reusing it ?

Thanks!

Links I have found useful:

http://greenliving.nationalgeographic.com/plastic-drink-bottles-safe-reuse-drinking-water-3110.html

http://www.plasticsinfo.org/Main-Menu/MicrowaveFood/Need-to-Know/Plastic-Bev-Bottles/The-Safety-of-Polyethylene-Terephthalate-PET.html

Answer (score 3):

It is probably not a chemical reaction that's the problem, it's that the container should be cleaned before it's refilled, and an unclean container might or will have bacteria.  While you're thinking 'refilled' might be in a matter if minutes, someone labeling the bottle is thinking about it sitting on a shelf with the cap off for months before reuse.  At that point there could be any number of unhealthy contaminants.

Comment: But as I understood from your words that it is safe to reuse these bottles if only they are cleaned. Is that means it can be reused ?

Comment: You might try http://biology.stackexchange.com .
In short - do not cultivate bacteria more than necessary. If you can wash and dry, do it, if not, don't. If it smells, definitely do wash and dry. If it does not help and you can afford it, throw away.

Answer (score 2):

PET bottles are perfectly safe for repeated use; they will not degrade or undergo any chemical change.

However, it IS very important to thoroughly wash (with soap and water), rinse and DRY the bottle so there is no moisture left in the bottle where bacteria might grow.  This is true of any type of bottle, but especially one with a narrow neck where it can be difficult to thoroughly dry the inside of the bottle.